# Getting error with basic Docker command (docker run hello-world)

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker on Windows 10, I tried the basic Docker command (docker run hello-world) but Docker return the error below:

> The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

I don't know if that is beacuse virtualization because my CPU does not support virtualization.

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.7
 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a
 Built:             Wed Jul 31 15:18:18 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Comment: If your CPU does not support virtualization, you cannot run any VM software.

Comment: so there is no solution

Comment: what is your windows edition ? Home or Professional ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mbyfieldcameron/docker-on-windows-10-home-edition-c186c538dff3

Comment: @lilylol probably yes, because you have to turn on the virtualization function in BIOS. When did you get the CPU? More than 10 years ago? Moden CPUs should all support virtualization.

Comment: Winows10 education N,                                                                                                     intel(R) pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz, 2200 GHz